# Flutter: how to put image(cropped) to next stateful/less widget

Tags: image, flutter, widget

i know there is a lot of q&a s like this with data, but how do i pass image to another screen? i have no idea and i'm stuck for four days please help...

```
_getFromGallery() async {
XFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
  source: ImageSource.gallery,
  maxWidth: 1800,
  maxHeight: 1800,
);
_cropImage(pickedFile!.path);




_cropImage(pickedFile) async {
File? croppedImage = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
  sourcePath: pickedFile,
  maxWidth: 1080,
  maxHeight: 1080,
);
if (croppedImage != null) {
  image = croppedImage;
  setState(() {
  });
}
```

}
}

and i need this cropped image to be at
`class CreatePage extends StatefulWidget`

any help will be so thankful!!

Comment: If you can share your whole widget flow or an example, that would be more helpful. But overall, you do not need to pass an image to the other class, you can pass the path or even file with your constructor. You can also pass the image as a widget in the constructor as well.

Answer (score 0):

simply pass the image object to next screen and use it in widget

Comment: thanks for the answer but how should i pass the image object to next screen? i am totally new to flutter...

Comment: please go through flutter cookbook for navigation